# Line numbering lineno and empheq

Tags: empheq, lineno

In my preamble,
I use

```
\usepackage[mathlines,right]{lineno}
```

for line numbering.

I use empheq for equation system, since I need the left bracket.

```
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}   
2x+y    &=  1 
\\   8x*y  &= 12 
\\   12x/c^2 &= 10 
\end{empheq}
```

[image]

It gives only one line numbering.
How do I make "all line have line numbering".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragments to small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: `CTAN` released new version of `lineno.sty`, please try with that, but not sure whether it meets the requirement.